# Restore session in yhat's Rodeo

Tags: python, rodeo

Is it possible to **restore** or **save** the last session and the last opened files in the python-IDE **[Rodeo](https://www.yhat.com/products/rodeo)** (developed by yhat)  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rodeo PM here, we're currently in the process of adding this feature.  You'll be able to relaunch and see all the scripts from your previous session.

Comment: FYI the v2.5.2 release includes an update that restores the last session (scripts, variables, history, etc)